# Yellow banner on top of interface and data loss

Tags: owncloud

I’ve got this yellow banner on top of the interface. Last night I synced my photos with my instance and nothing got uploaded but all photos are gone ! Erased !

When I click on more information I see errors:

```
    Transactional file locking should be configured to use memory-based locking, not the default slow database-based locking. See the documentation ↗ for more information.
    We recommend to enable system cron as any other cron method has possible performance and reliability implications.

    Some files have not passed the integrity check. Further information on how to resolve this issue can be found in our documentation. (List of invalid files… / Rescan…)

    The "Strict-Transport-Security" HTTP header is not configured to at least "15552000" seconds. For enhanced security we recommend enabling HSTS as described in our security tips.

    No memory cache has been configured. To enhance your performance please configure a memcache if available. Further information can be found in our documentation.
```

It gives me links where I can learn more about the problem but the links are dead (404)

What happened ??? I don't understand why all my photos got erased all at once. I bet other users must be pretty upset if they encountered this as well. Especially if someone runs an instance in commercial setting.

[image]

Comment: The important bit is "Some files have not passed the integrity check." Do what it recommends. But be prepared to restore your server from backup. One of the possible reasons for this is compromise.

Comment: Yeah ... I managed to recover all important data. Photos are gone though. I gotta make extra research about this 'coz I plan to use OwnCloud for business and this MUST NOT happen to sensitive data. Having a back up is a must that's for sure.

Comment: @MichaelHampton  What bothers me though that the links those warnings refering to are dead end. You get 404s on them. Not very helpful.

Comment: Is owncloud even still a thing? Its original developers left a few years back and formed Nextcloud, as I recall.

Comment: Well, OwnCloud devs released version 10.5 (supports latest PHP) only few months back so yeah it's being developed and maintained.

Comment: That hardly sounds like it's being developed and maintained! It sounds like it's on life support.

Comment: @MichaelHampton  Latest commit was pushed only 3 hours ago.

Comment: What files are invalid?  Try `integrity:check-core`  to  verify 
 https://doc.owncloud.com/server/10.5/admin_manual/configuration/server/occ_command/integrity_check_commands.html